# How can I write my profile in multiple languages on Careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, languages

I just accepted an invitation to [carreers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), and thought that it would be just *great* if there was any possibility to write my profile in multiple languages.

I know English is kind of *vernacular* in Programming languages, but I have the habit to write CV, list of publications, etc., in both my native language (a.k.a. French) and English, and think this is an excellent practice.

**Could it be possible to write a profile in several languages, and depending on the recruiter's profile, to display such or such language ?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 5):

We've had this on the backburner for some time.  I certainly agree having versions of your CV (for language purposes or otherwise) is desirable.  It's not on our current roadmap as we gear up for some other projects, but I do anticipate we'll get there eventually.

Status-Deferred answers make me feel empty inside, I wish I had better news.  Roadmaps can change, and we'll update here if we move this feature up in priority.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and @ChrisF for the edit): I perfectly understand that my proposal is a long-term goal, but I'm happy if it always appear on some kind of list, as a reminder on what could career be like. You already did an awesome work, keep moving!

Comment: This should be complete in about 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar : is your username relevant?